# Сортировка слов по количеству символов от большего к меньшему

Tags: java, сортировка

Суть задачи такова, что есть какой-то список слов к примеру: "Hi" + "Group" + "Java" + "stacks". И в исходном варианте он должен выглядеть примерно вот так:
Hi Java Group stacks

Задача вроде как не трудная, но у меня почему то с ней появились проблемы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String sentence = Stream.of("Hi","Group","Java","stacks")
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(sentence);
```